# Hijri to Gregorian not getting converted in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, microsoft-excel-365

I have a calendar in Hijri dates. I convert them to gregorian by typing the corresponding cell reference like =+A2. Then I format the value to gregorian date through Format Cell command. This has worked till now, but today it is not working. Try as I might, the cell simply types the same hijri date, and does not convert into gregorian.
I tried the Format Cell command, then I tried to add the custom format - B1mm/dd/yyyy, but that also did not change it into gregorian.
Any help would be really appreciated, since I have many calendars to manage and almost all of them have this problem.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's not working most likely because it's stored as text, if that's so, use [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885) as a guide to convert to number (dates are just numbers).

In any case, to convert to gregorian I suggest you to use

```
=TEXT(G9,"B1mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the cell formatting of the date, normally it is not possible to convert the date to a non-numeric format.

In addition, if you need to convert to Gregorian dates, you can also use the YEAR, MONTH, DAY functions.

See [YEAR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/year-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9).